# Android SQL Database returns null a String field with data that is really large

Tags: android, sql, android-studio, twitter, twitter4j

I'm using Twitter4J with the Twitter API to retrieve some Tweets (also called statuses) from Twitter.

I need to temporarily store these Statuses to a SQL database. The way that I do this is by converting the Status to a JSON String

```
statusItem.setmStatus(TwitterObjectFactory.getRawJSON(status));
```

Where status is a Status object, part of Twitter4J's library and statusItem is my own custom item.

However, when I save this statusItem to my database:

```
public void createStatusItem(StatusItem mStatus) {
    Log.d("StatusDBHelper","createStatusItem");

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(StatusItem.KEY_status, mStatus.mStatus);
    values.put(StatusItem.KEY_date, mStatus.mDate);
    values.put(StatusItem.KEY_user, mStatus.mUser);

    db.insert(StatusItem.TABLE, null, values);

    db.close();
}
```

I try to retrieve the StatusItem later like so:

```
status = TwitterObjectFactory.createStatus(statusItem.getmStatus());
```

However, statusItem.getmStatus is always null!! When I try to retrieve it from the database, it's too large so it doesn't get save into StatusItem's mStatus field!

How do I overcome such an issue in storing Statuses from Twitter into my SQL database for Android??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out, the null issue was occuring much sooner than the point at which I was saving my status to my statusitem.

For some reason:

```
TwitterObjectFactory.getRawJSON(status);
```

returns null no materr what. As a result, I turned to Google's GSON parser and converted it to a JSON object that way.

Clearly, TwitterObjectFactory has some issues.